# How to clear modal content after hide or close modal in angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

i want when i hide/close mdbModal , all content in modal reset. how can i do this in angular 4 or 5 ?

```
<div mdbModal #addSocialModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade top" id="addSocialModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="justify-content: center; max-width: 100%"
       role="document">
    <div class="modal-content addSocialModal-size modal-lg"
         style="text-align: center">


      <div class="modal-body mx-3 d-rtl" style="margin-top: 50px;margin-bottom: 10px">


        <a class="socialProject icon-telegram"
           (click)="onClickSocial('telegram')"
           style="border: 1px solid #19b4ff"
           [ngClass]="{'activeTelegram' : social == 'telegram' , 'icon-telegram-active': social == 'telegram'}"></a>

      </div>

      <li class="create-project-btn-position d-rtl" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">

        <button class="btn cancel-btn" (click)="closeAddSocialModal()">
          لغو
        </button>
        <button [disabled]="!submitSocialActive"
                type="submit" class="btn create-project-btn"
                (click)="onAddSocial()">
          اتصال اکانت
        </button>

      </li>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

i empty thing when modal want to open but i want to clear content when 
i click somewhere out of modal box and modal will be close.

how can i fix this problem ?